# SSL handshake error on a shared hosting account

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, wildcard

I've been trying to communicate with my hosting provider for over a month now, but I'm 99% sure they don't even read the tickets and respond with randomly generated string of words.

I searched for weeks for the answer to this, and I see some mentions in regards to updating Java or modifying files that I don't have access to. Now, this is what happens for me.  If I try to validate my domain name with W3C or try to validate a Twitter Card, I keep getting the SSL Handshake Error:

> ERROR: Fetching the page failed because SSL handshake error.

I have a wildcard SSL from Comodo.
If I remove these lines from .htaccess W3C validates, but Twitter Card doesn't:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.iadb.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^iadb.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Unfortunately if I change this, https is not enforced in any way, not to mention that it doesn't fix the Twitter issue. Again, since it's a shared host, I don't have access to any configuration other than .htaccess - I would appreciate any help or hints, even if it's just to tell me that I'm SOL.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting error? https://iadb.com/ seems to work fine, assuming that's your site.

Answer (score 0):

Some tests with `openssl s_client` and packet captures reveal that your server returns a TLS alert `unregognized_name` with level warning if you access the host as `iadb.com` but that the TLS alert does not happen when using `www.iadb.com` as hostname. But since you redirect from `https://www.iadb.com` to `http://iadb.com` you end up with a connection containing this TLS alert.

Although the TLS alert level is warning only some implementations (openssl 0.9.8, Java) interpret it as error which causes the handshake to fail. This is what you see for example with the W3C validator:

```
IO Error: handshake alert: unrecognized_name
```

While this client software obviously behaves wrong it is also bad that the server sends this TLS alert at all. My guess is that this is caused because the server is only configured for the hostname `www.iadb.com` but not for `iadb.com` but you explicitly use the latter name. One way to work around the problem by yourself is to use only `www.iadb.com`. Another way is to fix the server configuration which according to your description only can be done by the hosting provider.

Comment: I guess that makes total sense. Since the SSL has a wildcard it's probably not configured to handle the naked domain properly. I forced www. using the htaccess instead. That's probably going to cause issues for me with the search engines, but should pay off in the long run.  Thanks Steffen